# How to exclude a module from being uninstalled during import?

Tags: 8, configuration

On my local I have installed my custom module which depends on a contrib module.

I have removed both modules from the `core.extensions.yml` and added the following to settings.local.php.

```
$settings['config_exclude_modules'] = ['contrib_module', 'mymodule'];
```

But when I execute `drush cim`, both of the modules get uninstalled.

But I can read this specifically.

> When syncing configuration, if an excluded module is already
> installed, it will not be uninstalled by the configuration
> synchronisation, and dependent configuration will remain   intact.

Do I need to execute some command after adding it to the settings.php? Why it is not working.

Comment: Try `drush cim` before changing settings.php.

Comment: without changing settings.php if I run `drush cim` then how will drupal know the excluded modules?

Comment: Have you tried clearing cache after adding to settings.php but before `drush cim`?

Comment: Yes I cleared the cache before drush cim but still not working. Is it depends on the drush version?

Comment: If you remove any reference to the modules from core.extensions.yml, probably Drupal thinks the modules aren't installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will only work with drush 10. So drush should be updated to version 10.

With drush version lower than 10, it will work only from the UI.